# How to update this Excel Query to find the matched data and take other values

Tags: excel

I have this data in the first excel tab,
[image]

the first row has the tabs names, and the first column E037 .. is the material in the other tabs. The query will take E037 and go to every tab and find the match, if it is matched it will put an x under the tab's name

This is the query

```
IFERROR(IF(AND(MATCH($A37,$A:$A,0),MATCH($A37,'1709-Brownsburg'!$A:$A,0)),"x",),"")
```

What I want to change is instead of putting x, I want to put the Hardware Quantity for the matched material.

This is how all the data in the other tabs looks like

[image]

Comment: Probably just implement an Index in there. Have a look around for examples on index+match combo

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: You may find that reading [this](https://exceljet.net/index-and-match) article on the `INDEX` and `MATCH` combo will be helpfull enough.

Comment: That was so much help! Thank you!